# Windows Identity Foundation - FedAuth cookie expiration

Tags: wif

We're using the Windows Identity Foundation to implement a Single Sign-On solution for our application. The problem I'm encountering is that the FedAuth cookie isn't expiring when I think it should on the Relying Party side.

The FedAuth cookie isn't being destroying until approximately five minutes *after* its ValidTo time. For testing purposes I have the token lifetime and session set to timeout after ten minutes.

```
<sessionState timeout="10" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="..." />

<securityTokenHandlers>
  <add type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <sessionTokenRequirement lifetime="00:10" />
  </add>
</securityTokenHandlers>
```

We've implemented our own SessionAuthenticationModule because we're using sliding sessions. The code was taken pretty much verbatim from [Programming Windows Identity Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185) but I don't think that's the problem as I've tried commenting out the code in the SessionSecurityTokenReceived event and I'm seeing the same behavior, but just for completeness.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime validFrom = e.SessionToken.ValidFrom;
DateTime validTo = e.SessionToken.ValidTo;

double tokenLifetime = (validTo - validFrom).TotalMinutes;

if( now < validTo && now > validFrom.AddMinutes( tokenLifetime / 2 ) )
{
    SessionAuthenticationModule sam = sender as SessionAuthenticationModule;
    e.SessionToken = sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
        e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal, e.SessionToken.Context,
        now, now.AddMinutes( tokenLifetime ), e.SessionToken.IsPersistent );
    e.ReissueCookie = true;
}
```

If I sign into the app at 10:00am while debug the above code I can see the validTo value is 10:10am. I then let the app sit for eleven minutes and click on another link. In debugging the above I see that the value of now (10:11am) is indeed > validTo (10:10am) so the token expiration is not updated. At this point I would expect the SAM to destroy the FedAuth cookie. However, the FedAuth cookie is not destroyed, the value of Request.IsAuthenticated is still true (due to the presence of the cookie I'm assuming) and the user continues to access the application. It isn't until ~10:15am when I actually see the cookie being expired (using Fiddler).

I'm at a loss as to why the FedAuth cookie isn't being destroyed on the first access after the validTo time has expired. I can fudge it by setting my expiration times to be five minutes less than what I really want them to be, but I'd prefer to understand why I'm seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because there is a clock skew which by default I is set to 5 minutes. Typically clock skew is used to mitigate clock synchronization among servers (in this case servers of the same farm). If you want to disable or decrease that value you can do it by setting (from the top of my head)

`FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiuration.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);`

Just make sure that server clocks are 100% synchronized

Comment: I stumbled across this myself late last week, just didn't get around to updating the post. I understand why it exists, but it still seems there's a flaw in the implementation. I can let my timeout expire, then start using the system again (as long as I'm within the clock skew) and get logged out on the next click when the skew expires. I'll have to give this more thought on how the app should deal with it more gracefully.